# gmail apps is asking me to pay amount

Tags: google-workspace, gmail

I used gmail apps for free, now when i setup gmail apps for a new website, it says i need to pay 5$ per month. what happened to free gmail apps with 10 user accounts? Please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

Google have been down-playing the free versions of some of their services a bit recently. You don't actually link to what you're looking at, but I've found that depending upon how exactly you reach the Apps information pages, it might be harder to find the free 10-user option. It's [listed here](http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business/pricing.html).